# Can I run Virtual PC along with VirtualBox

Tags: windows, virtualbox, microsoft-virtual-pc

I have the Consumer Review of Windows 8 on my computer and Virtual PC was automatically installed. However, I know that it does not run on VirtualPC and so I would like to install VirtualBox to run it, but I am unsure if the different softwares will clash in some way. Can I run VirtualBox along with VirtualPC?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. They are different applications just like IE and firefox, as long as you have enough disk and memory.

Comment: Thanks. Just was unsure cause I have the XP Mode on VirtualPC

Answer (score 1):

If by "run" you mean "have installed", then yes, you shouldn't have any problems with that.

If by "run" you mean "run VMs in both programs at the same time", then no, that's a bad idea and will probably lead to crashes of the VMs or the host OS. I believe VirtualBox will even refuse to start if Virtual PC or another virtualisation program is already running. You might be able to trick it by starting VirtualBox first, and I've seen some people report that running VMs in both programs at the same time works if hardware virtualisation is disabled in one of them, but I'd still advise against it.

Comment: I'm not lookng to run VirtualPC at the same time as VirtualBox, but wondering if running VirtualBox with Windows 8 will somehow affect my computer as I have VirtualPC installed. Really, I do not want to use VirtualPC at all. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Phantom24 No, simply running VirtualBox will not affect your computer. Although, if you don't want to use Virtual PC at all, why not uninstall it?